# Using SSIS lookup to add additional column?

Tags: sql-server, ssis

can someone help with this? I have 2 tables that look like the below

HR

```
UserID     |    Date    |   Probation
552          01-01-2018         1
552          01-02-2018         1
552          01-03-2018         0
552          01-04-2018         0
```

Employee

```
UserID     |    Date    |   Actions
552          01-01-2018         234
552          01-02-2018         222
552          01-03-2018         109
552          01-04-2018         267
```

I would like to join the HR table onto the Employee table based on UserID and date being the same. I will then bring through the "Probation" flag from the HR table to determine which employees were in probation on which date in the Employee table.

I am using SSIS as both data sources are on different servers.

What would be the best way to achieve this? My ideal output would be something like

```
UserID     |    Date    |   Actions   | Probation
552          01-01-2018         234        1
552          01-02-2018         222        1
552          01-03-2018         109        0
552          01-04-2018         267        0
```

Thanks as always!

Comment: Lookup Transformation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/data-flow/transformations/lookup-transformation

Comment: Why does your subject line mention Lookup, but then your question sounds as though you don't know Lookup exists?   I'm very confused about exactly where you are stuck on this.

Comment: Looks like you need to join on both UserID and Date

Answer (score 2):

```
Create a data flow task with a source of Employee Table.
Add lookup to flow with HR Table and join lookup to data flow on UserID & Date
Then Add Probation a new column to Flow.
(You might want to set ignore lookup failure)
You can then write the results to a file or table.
```